# Bézier curve compute point from one axis

Tags: geometry, bezier, point, curve

I have a Cubic Bézier curve. But I have a problem when I need only one point. I have only value from the X-axis and want to find a value that coresponds to Y-axis to that point. Or find the t step, from it I can easely calculate the Y-axis.

Any clue how to do it? Or is there any formula to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parametric curve extends to any dimension by adding coefficients for those dimensions. Are you sure you've got things straight? It seems like you are using the x-axis as the curve parameter *t*. The *t* parameter controls the computations of X- and Y-coordinates by having two cubic equations. Take a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve) which provides some pretty neat explanations for the 2D case.

Edit:

Solve as a general third-degree polynomial. Beware that it might have 3 solutions, though.

Comment: Yes I know that t parameter controls the computations of X- and Y-coordinates. I have the value from X-axis and need the corespondig value from the Y-axis but unfortunately I don't know the t.

Comment: Use a bisect algorithm to approximate *t*, as heuristic use the distance from the known x-value to the currently computed x value based on current guess of *t*.

Comment: I thought there's a better solution. But this will have to do the trick ;) thanks bro.

Comment: I'm currently looking into a better, matrix-based method. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Any solution will have to deal with the fact that there may be multiple solutions if the curve is not [X monotone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). Consider the cubic bezier (0,0),(2,0),(-1,1),(1,1):

[image]

As you can see, there are 4 parameter values (and Y coordinates) at which X==1/2.

This means that if you use subdivision (which is probably your simplest solution), then you need to be careful that your initial bounding t values only surround the point you want.

You can also guess what this implies about the order of an algebraic solution.